# Access to private Maven Repository from Google Cloud Build?

Tags: maven, google-cloud-build

We're using Google Cloud Build to build a Spring Boot application written in Java. However, we have a private Maven repository (hosted on Artifact Registry if that matters), and the application won't build unless it has access to this repository.

The `cloudbuild.yaml` file looks like this:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: maven:3.8.6-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine
    entrypoint: mvn
    args: [ 'clean', 'verify', '-Dmaven.test.skip=true' ]
```

Usually, I add the credentials to the private maven repository to the `~/.m2/settings.xml` file.

What's the recommended approach to give Maven access to a private Maven repository when building the project with Google Cloud Build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional [step in Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema) to generate credentials and store them in the file (`~/.m2/settings.xml`), before running the maven step:

```yaml
###### previous Cloud Build Steps ###

- name: 'bash'
  args: ['./cloudbuild_credentials.sh'] ### <--- script to generate creds
  dir: 'src'                            ### <--- directory might be different
  id: 'generate-credentials'
  env:
      - PRIVATE_REPO_PASS=$_PRIVATE_REPO_PASS ### <--- keys might be passed to Cloud Build via Triggers

###### next Cloud Build Steps ###
```

An example how the script (`cloudbuild_credentials.sh`) might look like (generates and saves `~/.m2/settings.xml` file with the sensitive data):

```bash
printf '
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>private-repo</id>
            <username>xyz</username>
            <password>%s</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
' "${PRIVATE_REPO_PASS}" > ~/.m2/settings2.xml
```

This way you commit only non-sensitive data to the repo, and you pass the key from the outside. For example via [Google Cloud Build Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@star67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8189903/star67)'s answer:

#### Persist the `settings.xml` file between steps

Unlike the answer above, I don't recommend putting your file under `~` or `$HOME` as it won't be persisted after the step is completed.

Instead, you can use `/workspace` which is the default volume created by Cloud Build retaining its content between steps:

```bash
printf '
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>private-repo</id>
            <username>xyz</username>
            <password>%s</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
' "${PRIVATE_REPO_PASS}" > /workspace/.m2/settings2.xml
```

See the documentation page [Passing data between build steps](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/pass-data-between-steps).

#### Access your Maven password stored in Secret Manager

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'bash'
    args: ['./cloudbuild_credentials.sh']
    dir: 'src'
    id: 'generate-credentials'
    secretEnv: ['PRIVATE_REPO_PASS']

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/${PROJECT_NUMBER}/secrets/${name-of-your-secret}/versions/latest
      env: 'PRIVATE_REPO_PASS'
```

See the documentation page [Use secrets from Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets?hl=fr).

#### Use a custom `settings.xml` with the `pack` CLI

If you build your app using buildpacks, use the environment variable `GOOGLE_BUILD_ARGS` to set the path to `settings.xml`:

```yaml
  - name: gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack
    entrypoint: pack
    args:
      - build
      - '$_DEPLOY_REGION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$_REPOSITORY/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - --builder
      - gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:latest
      - --env
      - 'GOOGLE_BUILD_ARGS=--settings /workspace/.m2/settings.xml'
```

See the documentation page [Building a Java application](https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/java#hosted_maven_central_mirror).

All the steps are [documented on my GitHub](https://github.com/axel-op/google-cloud-build-maven-settings).